# Xamarin Android Httppost Request

Tags: xamarin, webclient

I am trying to make a post call to my web Api which is on local host. But I am getting following error

> result = {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x0005e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/f4db8a57/source/mono/mcs/class/System/Sy...

Can anyone help? Below is my code:

```
private void click (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInfo user = new UserInfo(1, "hellohello@gmail.com", "helloss");
        String data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://192.168.206.2:155/api/register"), data);
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += Wc_UploadStringCompleted;
    }

    private void Wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Error;
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your WebApi project while running the xamarin app to make sure it's not an issue with your server code?

Comment: @chriszumberge check my edited question.

Comment: try adding an accept header to your WebClient.. wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: I'd bet it's not the *accept* but the *Content-type* Header you are missing. Should be application/json too.

Comment: it worked @KaiBrummund.. thanks a million. plz add it as an answer so I may accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the Server only get's a string from you and can't know if, it is json, xml or something else. You just have to tell him.

You can to this on a `WebClient` via:

```
wc.Add("Content-Type", "aplication/json");
```

If you are using the `HttpClient` you have to set ist via the `Content` property:

```
request.Content = new StringContent("json", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP specification states:

415 Unsupported Media Type
The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by the target resource for this method. The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content- Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

It seems your server is having troubles with the format... try adding the headers with .Add("Accept", "aplication/json");